# Why fragment shader is faster than just rendering texture?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I checked something and I got weird result about performance with C++ & OpenGL & GLSL.

In the first program I drew pixels to texture with fragment shader and then render the texture.
The texture's mag\min was `GL_NEAREST`.

In the second program I took the fragment shader and rendered directly to the screen.

Why the second program is faster? Isn't rendering texture faster instead of repeating the same action?

It's like taking a video of AAA game and then show it on the same computer and get lower FPS with the video.

The fragment shader is:

```
uniform int mx,my;

void main(void) {
    vec2 p=gl_FragCoord.xy;
    p-=vec2(mx,my);
    if (p.x<0.0)
        p.x=-p.x;
    if (p.y<0.0)
        p.y=-p.y;
    float dis=sqrt(p.x*p.x+p.y*p.y);
    dis+=(abs(p.x)+abs(p.y))-(abs(p.x)-abs(p.y));
    p.x/=dis;
    p.y/=dis;
    gl_FragColor=vec4(p.x,p.y,0.0,1.0);
}
```

Comment: Rendering this directly to the screen will not involve any texture reads, so this will most likely be faster. Offscreen rendering is not necessarily faster, but more practical. A fragment shader can also write to multiple textures. Proper profiling is needed. How did you determine what was faster?

Comment: @Grimmy `clock_t` and `clock` before and after the SwapBuffers.

Answer (score 6):

As usual with performance questions, about the only way to be really certain would be to use  a profiler.

That said, my guess would be that this is mostly a question of processing bandwidth versus memory bandwidth. To render a texture, the processor has to read data from one part of memory, and write that same data back to another part of memory.

To directly render from the shader, the processor only has to write the output to memory, but doesn't have to read data in from memory.

Therefore, it's a question of which is faster: reading that particular data from memory, or generating it with the processing units? The math in your shader is pretty simple (essentially the only part that's at all complex is the `sqrt`) -- so at least with your particular hardware, it appears that it's a little faster to compute the result than read it from memory (at least given the other memory accesses going on at the same time, etc.)

Note that the two (shader vs. texture) have quite different characteristics. Reading a texture is going to be nearly constant speed, regardless of how simple or complex of computation was involved in creating it. Not to state the obvious, but a shader is going to run fast if the computation is simple, but slow down (potentially a lot) if the computation as the computation gets complex. In the AAA games you mention, it's fair to guess that at least some of the shaders use complex enough calculations that they'll almost certainly be slower than a texture read. At the opposite extreme a really trivial shader (e.g., one that just passes the fragment color through from input to output) is probably quite a lot faster than reading from a texture.

Comment: I concur. Because of the time differences between shader/texture processing we have techniques such as lightmapping that use textures to generate lights around scenes because it is calculated much more efficiently than doing the same in a shader and can save a lot of processing time, especially on consoles. It really all comes down to the setup of the machine, and the only way you can guarantee what is optimal is by trying it yourself.

Comment: Then the little `texture2D` is slower than all of that code? Isn't there a faster replacement for this? I don't mind about the quality I don't need to blur the texture in rendering.

Comment: @FijiWiji: Yes, texture accesses are slow. The bottleneck is the memory bandwidth available and that's a hardware limitation. You could make the texture smaller, to decrease the bandwidth requirements, but that's about it. To put it into perspective: With a cold texture cache modern GPUs require up to 200 clock cycles for a memory access to finish. 200 clock cycles in which a lot of can be computed. Because of these latencies GPUs have very large texture caches, but if texture fetches have a bad pattern those caches will be useless.

Comment: @datenwolf I can't access it directly like an array?

Comment: @FijiWiji: Actually accessing textures directly, as in a raw array is even slower than using texel fetch functions. To be fast, texture access addresses must be properly aligned. The texture caches largely improve memory throughput for aligned, well behaving access patterns.

Comment: @datenwolf I tried aligning the `TexCoord` to the center of the pixels in textures but nothing better...

Comment: @FijiWiji: When I talk about alignment I don't mean spatial alignment. I talk about memory addressing alignmentm which is a completely different beast. Although it's not about OpenGL shaders I strongly recommend you read the CUDA documentation (CUDA is much closer to the GPU hardware and you actually have to deal with such things like memory aligned access http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-best-practices-guide/index.html)